# spring batch run sql script as a tasklet

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Does spring batch support executing a sql scripts as part of a tasklet?  Below are the sequence of steps that I'm planning to develop with spring batch.

For step 2 and 4 I need to run bunch of sql statements in sequence. How can I accomplish running a sql script?

1. Read csv files and validate the contents
2. if valid content, Execute a sql script that drop existing tables, and re-create tables, index etc
3. Run the writer operations to insert the data into the table.
4. Run sequence of stored procedures described in the .sql file.

Comment: for step 4 you could go with standard chunk processing, filereader reads the stored procedures, writer executes them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't believe Spring Batch specifically supports what you're asking for, you could take a look at [ScriptUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils.html) to see if it provides the behavior you're looking for.

If not, depending on the complexity of your SQL there is the option of using `JdbcTemplate` directly within a `Tasklet` and creating a series of `Tasklets`

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  You approached has worked out for me well.  But, however, ScriptUtils just runs the stored procedure.  But, I don't see a way to use return any update counts back.

Comment: You are correct - most methods in that class do not return anything. I wasn't aware that returning an update count was required. If that is the case you may need to look into separate JdbcTemplates or if having your SQL store the number of records updated to a log of sorts and retrieving the value from the log is feasible

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  I will follow your adrive

Comment: the link to ScriptUtils (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils.html) was very helpful, thanks