# Empty target database tables using SQL Script in Spring Batch + Spring Boot

Tags: spring, migration, spring-batch

Currently, I want to migrate the data from one database (source) to another database (target). Since the target database is also filled with data I want to remove it before the migration starts. I have written an SQL Script to do the data deletion and tested it manually but I want it to be a part of the BatchConfiguration, so it will be executed automatically every time I start the migration process but before migrating the actual data. Any suggestions on how this can be done because I have read several posts stating that it's not possible to execute SQL Script in BatchConfiguration, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445503/spring-batch-run-sql-script-as-a-tasklet) ...

Comment: What about a first step in your job that deletes records from the target table?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine That's what I taught as well but I don't know how to write it to execute the whole script as a first step ...

Comment: The answer in the link you shared is the way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37450553/5019386. Create a tasklet step and use spring jdbc goodies (or any JDBC API you want) to call the script that deletes records from the table.